# Shared memory, and multiple philosophers eating

Tags: c

I've got my code down for a dining philosopher problem, using shared memory. The issue I'm encountering is that 3 of 5 philosophers are eating which shouldn't be happening. Where am I going wrong in my code?

Updated: still not working right. Philosophers seem to not be going through one of the states

```
#include <stdio.h>          // needed for printf, sprintf, ...
#include <stdlib.h>         // needed for exit()
#include <unistd.h>         // needed for sleep, fork, waitpid, _exit, ftruncate
#include <sys/wait.h>       // needed for waitpid
#include <fcntl.h>          // For O_* constants
#include <sys/mman.h>       // needed for mmap, munmap and associated constants
#include <semaphore.h>

void philosopher(int i);
int parent(void);
void take_forks(int i);
void put_forks(int i);
void test (int i);
void think(int i);
void eat(int i);

#define N               5           /* number of philosophers */
#define THINKING        0           /* philosopher is thinking */
#define HUNGRY          1           /* philosopher is trying to get for ks */
#define EATING          2           /* philosopher is eating */
#define FINISH          3
#define LEFT (arga+4)%N
#define RIGHT (arga+1)%N

struct shared_memory {
int k;
int state[N];
sem_t s[N];
sem_t mutex;
};

struct shared_memory *shared;
int fd_shm, fd_log;

int main(void) {

    if ((fd_shm = shm_open ("/test", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0660)) == -1)
        printf("error");
    if (ftruncate (fd_shm, sizeof (struct shared_memory)) == -1)
        printf("error");
    if ((shared = mmap (NULL, sizeof (struct shared_memory), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,fd_shm, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        printf("error");

    // Initialize the shared memory
    shared -> k = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N;i++){
        shared -> state[i] = 0;
        sem_init(&shared->s[i],0,1);
    }

    sem_init(&shared->mutex,1,1);

    pid_t pids[N];

    // At the beginning every philosopher is thinking
      for (int l = 0; l < N; l++){
        shared ->state[l]=THINKING;
      }

    printf("Start");

    for(int j=0; j< N; j++){

        if((pids[j] = fork()) < 0){
            printf("failed");
            perror("fork");
        }else if (pids[j] == 0 ){
            int pid = getpid();
            printf("pids[%d] = %d\n",j,pid);
            philosopher(j);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    parent();

    for (int m=0; m<N;m++){
        waitpid(pids[m],NULL,0);
    }

    printf("This is final k %d\n",shared->k);

    if (munmap(shared, sizeof(struct shared_memory)) == -1) {
        printf("Function munmap() failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if ((shm_unlink("/test")) == -1){
        printf("Function shm_unlink() failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void philosopher(int arga) {
    //int count =0;

    //while(count<5){
    while(1){
        //sleep(1);
        //think(i);
        take_forks(arga);
        sleep(2);
        //eat(i);
        //sleep(1);
        put_forks(arga);
        //count++;
    }
    shared->state[arga] = FINISH;
}

void take_forks(int arga) /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
{
    //printf("arga take_fork: %d\n", arga);

    sem_wait(&shared->mutex);       /* enter critical region, down mutex */
    shared->state[arga] = HUNGRY;       /* record fact that philosopher i is hungry */
    //while (shared->state[i] == HUNGRY){
    test(arga);                         /* try to acquire 2 forks */
    sem_post(&shared->mutex);       /* exit critical region, up mutex */

    //sem_wait(&shared->s[arga]);       /* block if forks were not acquired, down philosopher*/

    //}


    //sleep(1);
}
void put_forks(int arga)                /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
{
    //printf("arga put_fork: %d\n", arga);
    sem_wait(&shared->mutex);       /* enter critical region, down mutes */
    //test(LEFT);                   /* see if left neighbor can now eat */
    //test(RIGHT);                  /* see if right neighbor can now eat */
    shared->state[arga] = THINKING;     /* philosopher has finished eating */
    sem_post(&shared->mutex);       /* exit critical region, up mutex */


}
void test(int arga)                     /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
{
    sem_wait(&shared->s[LEFT]);
    sem_wait(&shared->s[RIGHT]);

    shared->state[arga]= EATING;
    sleep(1);

    sem_post(&shared->s[RIGHT]);
    sem_post(&shared->s[LEFT]);
    //if (shared->state[arga] == HUNGRY && shared->state[LEFT] != EATING && shared->state[RIGHT] != EATING)
    //{
        //printf("Philosopher: %d (i+N-1)%N - %d", i, ((i+N-1)%N));
        //shared->state[arga] = EATING;
        //sleep(2);
        //sem_post(&shared->s[arga]); //Up philosopher
    //}

}

void think(int arga){
    //printf("I am philosopher %d i am thinking\n", i);
    sleep(2);
}

void eat(int arga){
    //printf("I am philosopher %d i am eating\n", i);
    sleep(3);
}

int parent(void){
    puts("This is the Parent Process");
    int philosopherState;
    char* philprint;
    int count=0;
    int c;

    while (1){
        sleep(1);
        //sem_wait(&shared->mutex);
        for(int o = 0; o<N;o++ ){

            /*philosopherState = shared->state[o];

             if (philosopherState == 0) {
                 philprint = "Thinking";
             }else if(philosopherState == 1){
                 philprint = "Eating";
             }else if(philosopherState == 2){
                 philprint = "Hungry";
             }else if(philosopherState == 3){
                 philprint = "Gone";
                 count++;
             }*/
            sem_getvalue(&shared->s[o], &c);
            //printf("P%d %s \t",o, philprint);

            if (c==0){
                printf("P%d Thinking\t",o);
            }
            else if(c==1){
                printf("P%d Eating\t",o);
            }
            else if (c==2){
                printf("P%d Hungry\t",o);
            }
            else if (c==3){
                printf("P%d Gone\t",o);
            }

             if (count >4){
                 break;
             }
        }
        //sem_post(&shared->mutex);
         printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

        //while(count<5){
        while(1){
            //sleep(1);
            //think(i);
            take_forks(arga);
            sleep(2);
            //eat(i);
            //sleep(1);
            put_forks(arga);
            //count++;
        }
        shared->state[arga] = FINISH;
    }

    void take_forks(int arga) /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
    {
        //printf("arga take_fork: %d\n", arga);

        sem_wait(&shared->mutex);       /* enter critical region, down mutex */
        shared->state[arga] = HUNGRY;       /* record fact that philosopher i is hungry */
        //while (shared->state[i] == HUNGRY){
        test(arga);                         /* try to acquire 2 forks */
        sem_post(&shared->mutex);       /* exit critical region, up mutex */

        //sem_wait(&shared->s[arga]);       /* block if for ks were not acquired, down philosopher*/

        //}


        //sleep(1);
    }
    void put_forks(int arga)                /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
    {
        //printf("arga put_fork: %d\n", arga);
        sem_wait(&shared->mutex);       /* enter critical region, down mutes */
        //test(LEFT);                   /* see if left neighbor can now eat */
        //test(RIGHT);                  /* see if right neighbor can now eat */
        shared->state[arga] = THINKING;     /* philosopher has finished eating */
        sem_post(&shared->mutex);       /* exit critical region, up mutex */


    }
    void test(int arga)                     /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
    {
        sem_wait(&shared->s[LEFT]);
        sem_wait(&shared->s[RIGHT]);

        shared->state[arga]= EATING;
        sleep(1);

        sem_post(&shared->s[RIGHT]);
        sem_post(&shared->s[LEFT]);
        //if (shared->state[arga] == HUNGRY && shared->state[LEFT] != EATING && shared->state[RIGHT] != EATING)
        //{
            //printf("Philosopher: %d (i+N-1)%N - %d", i, ((i+N-1)%N));
            //shared->state[arga] = EATING;
            //sleep(2);
            //sem_post(&shared->s[arga]); //Up philosopher
        //}

    }

    void think(int arga){
        //printf("I am philosopher %d i am thinking\n", i);
        sleep(2);
    }

    void eat(int arga){
        //printf("I am philosopher %d i am eating\n", i);
        sleep(3);
    }

    int parent(void){
        puts("This is the Parent Process");
        int philosopherState;
        char* philprint;
        int count=0;
        //int c;

        while (1){
            sleep(1);

            for(int o = 0; o<N;o++ ){
                philosopherState = shared->state[o];

                 if (philosopherState == 0) {
                     philprint = "Thinking";
                 }else if(philosopherState == 1){
                     philprint = "Eating";
                 }else if(philosopherState == 2){
                     philprint = "Hungry";
                 }else if(philosopherState == 3){
                     philprint = "Gone";
                     count++;
                 }
                //sem_getvalue(&shared->s[o], &c);
                printf("P%d %s \t",o, philprint);
                //printf("P%d %s\t",o, c == 0 ? "Eating" : "Hungry");

                 if (count >4){
                     break;
                 }
            }
             printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried walking through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, but I can't get into viewing each child process to see what the variables are sitting at.

Comment: You realize you don't need to explicitly set up shared memory if you `fork()` after `mmap()`?

Comment: EOF, I'm a little confused by what you mean. To fork, I need to create my child processes, but they need to access the shared variables for the sempahores and mutexes

Comment: Could it be how I initialize my semaphores?

Comment: I've got it now to a point where I only have two philosophers eating, but it's not cycling through all 3 statuses

Comment: Can you upload the new code?

Comment: It's uploaded to the latest